# CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera) is obsolete

Tags: android, xamarin, permissions, request

```
var permissionStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Camera);
if (permissionStatus != Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
    await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Camera);
}
```

IPermissions.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission) is obselete: CheckPermissionStatusAsync is deprecated, please use CheckPermissionStatusAsync instead.

How should I use this method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

old

```
await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Camera);
```

new ([docs](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin#api-usage))

```
await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionAsync<CameraPermission>();
```

Comment: (no 's' at `Permission`) -> await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionAsync<CameraPermission>();